# Oracle SQL Query -- records since 2017

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have a monster query in which I need to return any records that were created since 01/01/2017 but DataGrip is returning

> [42000][904] ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier Position: 1283

```
SELECT
       inh.inh_auto_key, inh.invc_number,
       inh.invoice_date, inh.ship_date, inh.post_status, inh.post_date,
       pnm.pn, pnm.description,
       stm.serial_number, stm.unit_freight_cost,
       sod.unit_price, sod.unit_cost, sod.qty_invoiced, sod.sod_auto_key,
       condition_code,
       salesperson_code,
       so_number,
       ind.route_code, ind.ind_auto_key,
       company_name, company_code,
       consignment_code,
       term_code, due_days
FROM
  invc_header inh
    JOIN invc_detail ind ON ind.inh_auto_key = inh.inh_auto_key
    JOIN so_detail sod ON sod.sod_auto_key = ind.sod_auto_key
    JOIN so_header soh ON soh.soh_auto_key = sod.soh_auto_key
    JOIN part_condition_codes pcc ON pcc.pcc_auto_key = sod.pcc_auto_key
    LEFT JOIN salesperson spn on spn.spn_auto_key = soh.spn_auto_key
    JOIN companies cmp ON cmp.cmp_auto_key = soh.cmp_auto_key
    LEFT JOIN stock_reservations str ON str.sod_auto_key = sod.sod_auto_key
    LEFT JOIN stock stm ON stm.stm_auto_key = str.stm_auto_key
    LEFT JOIN parts_master pnm on pnm.pnm_auto_key = stm.pnm_auto_key
    LEFT JOIN consignment_codes cnc on cnc.cnc_auto_key = stm.cnc_auto_key
    LEFT JOIN term_codes tmc on tmc.tmc_auto_key = cmp.tmc_auto_key
WHERE ind.route_code IN ('M', 'E', 'S')
  AND Year(inh.invoice_date) > 2017
```

Comment: That looks like a standard Oracle function https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefyearfunc.html

Comment: BTW, you should use `>=`. Otherwise it starts with `1/1/2018`.

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: I don't really know which version

Comment: The `YEAR` function doesn't exist in recent releases, you have to use `EXTRACT`.

Answer (score 0):

It is still grinding but I think this will work

```
WHERE ind.route_code IN ('M', 'E', 'S')
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR from inh.invoice_date) > 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
inh.invoice_date > date '2017-01-01'
```

While the code you posted, that uses `extract()`, is valid in Oracle, the above solution is more efficient. Because no function is applied on the column that is being filtered, this can take advantage of an index on the date column. On the other hand, your solution requires applying the function to the entire column before the filtering can happen. The performance penalty increases quickly as the number of rows to filter gets larger.

In technical terms, one says that the above expression is *SARGable*, which stands for Search Argument Able.